# What do you call the document containing all of the details of a secret mission?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the document containing all of the details of a secret mission? I know the "mission briefing" expose the details of the mission, but what do you call the document and not the event where the details of the mission is being put forth? By secret mission, I mean a mission that has to be performed by a spy or a secret agent like James Bond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use the word

> [Dossier](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dossier)

A set of papers containing information about an event, person, mission, etc